# Concatenating two tar files

Tags: tar

I have two large files, a.tar.xz and b.tar.xz. Since they are two consecutive versions of the same application, if I combine them I will get a file that is much smaller than the sum of the sizes of the two original files.

I want to avoid using temporary disk space if possible. So I was thinking of doing this:

```
cat <(xz -dc a.tar.xz) <(xz -dc b.tar.xz) > a+b.tar.xz
```

However, the [tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/concatenate.html#concatenate) says we shouldn't combine two tar files using `cat`. But the `tar --concatenate` option requires the tarfile to be present and not a pipe.

Is there a way I can combine the two tar files as above but with the result being a valid (compressed) tarfile?

Comment: Since this is xz this is your [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151705/407300)

Comment: @NicolasFormichella well, that really doesn't address the core issue: having duplicate files occupy space only once!

Comment: @MarcusMüller the `xz` compression will deal with duplicate files in the combined tar file: it will compress them well because it's repeated data.

Comment: @k314159 nah, the default XZ window sizes are far too small for that.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella thanks, but I was hoping to avoid creating a "slightly corrupt" archive (as that answer puts it) which can only be extracted with the non-standard `--ignore-zeros` option.

Comment: @k314159 hm, speaking in terms of your application: wouldn't it break functionality if you just overwrote an unpacked a.tar's contents with b.tar's contents?

Comment: @MarcusMüller no, the tar files contain directory trees `app-version-1.2.3/...` and `app-version-1.2.4/...` respectively.

Comment: @k314159 but then there'd be not much size reduction for the reason I mentioned above to Nicolas: You have to store two copies of the file, and unless the distance between the beginnings of the two files (which are in tar inherently stored linearly) is smaller than 64 MB (for maximum compression settings of `xz`! You can, theoretically, even increase that size to up to 1.5 GB, but your compression will not finish this year…), that doesn't "compress away".

Comment: @k314159 in other words, if that is your goal, `tar` is the wrong tool, and `xz` isn't the right configuration of the underlying compression algorithm.

Comment: @k314159 hm, you could use the facilities used by tar to represent hardlinks. But that would entail writing a bit of code in a proper programming language with a tar-writing library, not just a shell script.